# Firebase get Value and change/update it

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I previously asked the almost same question. But the answer wasn't that good or just not good enough. I wanted to start again and now I have a lot of problems.

Here is the post.

[Making a database-voting app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555452/making-a-database-voting-app)

So for now I have another idea.

This time there is only one value which counts the votes, but the app don't get the actual amount of the value "count".

Here is my code:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
names= database.getReference("Test");

final Name name = new Name(txtName.getText().toString(), score);
names.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.child(name.getName()).exists()) {
                up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        names.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                score = dataSnapshot.child("Test").child("Name").getValue(long.class);
                                score += 1;
                                final Name name = new Name(txtName.getText().toString(), score);
                                try {
                                    names.child(name.getName()).setValue(name);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            }
                        });

                        Toast.makeText(Result.this, "Thank you for voting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Intent homeIntent3 = new Intent(Result.this, StartActivity.class);
                        startActivity(homeIntent3);
                    }
                });
```

Here's the database

[image]

So if the name doesn't exist I easily can add the up/down vote with score = 1 or score = -1.

But if the name exists, there is a problem with changing the score value.

The app is crashing with the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
                  at user.prof.name.Activities.Result$1$1$1.onDataChange(Result.java:80)
                  at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzap.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:75)
                  at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzca.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:63)
                  at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzcd$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:55)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6589)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

And this is the error line in the code

```
score = dataSnapshot.child("Test").child("Name").getValue(long.class);
```

I'm not an expert in the database programming, but what is wrong?
The wrong child?

I also tried to save the "score" as a String and parse it to a long value. But that's not also working.

Comment: First thing I see is that `Name` is not an attribute for itself and also you have a separate node for storing the actual value. I would do the code like this: `score = dataSnapshot.child("Test").child("Name1").child("Name1").getValue(String.class);`

Comment: Thank you. But with this I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't getting anything because the name of your `Name` property is in every child is different. To solve this, you should have the same name under each child like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- test
       |
       --- Name1
       |     |
       |     --- name: "Name1"
       |     |
       |     --- score: 0
       |
       --- Name2
             |
             --- name: "Name2"
             |
             --- score: 15
```

See, the name of the `name` property is now always `name` and **not** name1, name2 and so on.

To get the value of your `score` properties within all objects, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("test").orderByChild("name");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            long score = ds.child("score").getValue(Long.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "Score: " + score);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
Score: 0
Score: 15
```

Please also note that I have passed to the `getValue(Long.class)`, the `Long` class and not the primitive long.

**Edit:**

To edit a single entry, then you should use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("score", 5);
rootRef.child("test").child("Name1").updateChildren(map);
```

The `score` property in the first object will be changed from `0` to `5`. If you think that your `score` property will updated in an multi user environment, then you should use [FirebaseTransactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) as explained my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307610/how-to-save-users-score-in-firebase-and-retrieve-it-in-real-time-in-android-stud)**.

Comment: Thank you @Alex Mamo. I get the whole list and I can increase all of them and change the score value, but how can I edit only one entry? I don't get it... So if Name1 already exists, how can I only increase that entry? I've tried a few things, but nothing is working...

Comment: Sorry. Unfortunately, the question has not yet been answered 100%. If I accept the answer now, then unfortunately no one helps me anymore.
I have edited on my first answer to your answer.

Comment: I see the edited comment. So if you want to edit a single entry then please see my updated answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the right way. I only have two mistakes. How can I get the actual value of the score? If I'm adding `score--; map.put("count", score);` then it always starts at 0 and counts one down. When I'm adding `score++;` it counts infinitely high. A for-loop it counts also till infinity

Comment: Good to hear that and you're welcome Hansi! "How can I get the actual value of the score?" You should post another fresh question for that, so me and other users can help you.